# checking for the number of arguments in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I got a problem. Let's say I have a cmds command, it takes no arguments. And if the user writes this command and after it something else, for example >cmds qqq (greater than sign is a prefix), then the command will still be executed. I need the commands to be executed only if it does not accept arguments, then the user should not provide anything for the entire command. And if the command, for example, takes 3 arguments, then it will be executed only if the user specifies 3 arguments, and not more. How can I do it?

My simplest command code:

```
@bot.command()
async def cmds(ctx):
    await ctx.send('no commands')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet you provided currently doesn't take any arguments, if you want to get an unlimited number of args and count them

```py
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, *args):
    no_args = len(args)
    await ctx.send(f"{no_args} args")
```

Invoking

```
{prefix}foo one two three
3 args
{prefix}foo one two 
2 args
```